# Make this code read from file

Tags: linux, bash

Hello guys I wrote code in linux shell script but the code only read from keyboard i want to change it to read from file for example if i write ./car.sh lamborghini.txt it should give me most expensive model of it.

code is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Choose one of them"
read manu
sort -t';' -nrk3 auto.dat > auto1.dat
grep $manu auto1.dat | head -n1 | cut -d';' -f2
```

and auto.dat file contains these:

```
Lamborghini;Aventador;700000
Lamborghini;Urus;200000
Tesla;ModelS;180000
Tesla;ModelX;140000
Ford;Mustang;300000
Ford;Focus;20000
```

Comment: Please format your code and the file information.

Comment: I really don't understand the question...

Comment: I mean the first code that i wrote it sort the auto.dat file from expensive to cheap and send it auto1.dat file and when it asks me chose one of them for example i wrote Tesla and it gives me expensive model of tesla to me but i dont want to write it i want it to read from file for example if i wrote ./car.sh lamborghini.txt it should give me expensive model of lamborghini or ./car.sh tesla.txt like this

Comment: Don't elaborate on your problem in comments. Update your Q with sample input, required output, code  current output and error messages (some of which you have already) AND your thoughts about why its not working. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` command always reads from stdin. You can use *redirection* `<` to read the content of a file.

## Reading `$manu` from a file's content

```
#!/bin/sh
read manu < "$1"
sort -t';' -nrk3 auto.dat | grep "$manu" | head -n1 | cut -d';' -f2
```

This version of your script expects a file name as a command line parameter. The first line of said file will be stored in `$manu`. Example:

```
./car.sh fileWithSelection.txt
```

The file should contain the text you would have entered in your old script.

## Reading `$manu` from a command line parameter

In my opinion, it would make more sense to interpret the command line parameters directly, instead of using files and passing them to the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
manu="$1"
sort -t';' -nrk3 auto.dat | grep "$manu" | head -n1 | cut -d';' -f2
```

Example:

```
./car.sh "text you would have entered in your old script."
```

Comment: so this will help my code to read from file not from the keyboard right ?

Comment: @Frost Yes, the first version reads a file instead of waiting for keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way but the file Tesla.txt must contain Tesla

```
#!/bin/sh
read manu < "$1"
awk -F\; -vmod="$manu" '
  $1==mod{if($3>a){a=$3;b=$2}}
  END{if(b){print "The more expensive "mod" is "b" at "a}}' auto.dat
```